# Query System Stop Words in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

How can I query the list of system stop words in SQL Server? I need to be able to do this without creating a new stop list that copies the system stop list.

Comment: This was way too hard to find. Google didn't even bring up this post when I searched for it. The "informational" warning uses the term noise word when they are encountered. I would add more keywords to your post to help drive searches to it. Add the words or phrases to catch "how do I query the default list of noise words in SQL Server." I was going to create this exact post to help others find it, but since it exists could you try to add text to drive searches to this post. I only found it by searching for fulltext_system_stopwords and that isn't much help. +1Q/+1A.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT  stopword
FROM    sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ssw
WHERE   language_id = 1033;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!